# Springboot: how to set external location for profile file only?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an internal application.yml that specifies common properties and the profile:

```
spring.profiles.active: dev
spring.config.location: 'C:\externalConf\'
spring.application.name: myAppName
myproperty: aprop
```

Then I put my application-dev.yml in  C:\externalConf\ but it seems it is not read.

Where is the problem?

Comment: it this resolved using the answer.

Comment: Yes, just marked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass config folder location like this:

```
spring.config.location=file:///C:externalConf/
```